# How can I tell that a domain transfer has been successful?

Tags: domain, name, switch

I'm currently transferring from Fasthosts (UK) to 123-reg. Whe WHOIS database says the domain is with 123-reg, but it isn't. Has something gone wrong here, or does it just take a while? Also, will the domain disappear from my Fasthosts control panel when the transfer is complete?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has been more than 24 hours I would recommend asking 123-reg to confirm the transfer has happened correctly and the correct IPS Tag has been used. If it has been less than 24 hours then just wait.

On a side note when you say that it hasn't disappeared from Fasthosts and appeared in 123-reg are you looking at the domain name part of the control panel or the hosting part of the control panel. You can configure any host to work with any domain name, in theory I could setup an account with Fasthosts to answer to "www.google.com", however seeing as the DNS entry wouldn't point to it no pages would ever be requested.

Answer (score 1):

The transfer will be complete when:

1. the WHOIS name servers are right (123-reg dns o what you specified)
2. the above name servers are properly configured

I don't know the Fasthosts control panel but usually the domain is in the list until the domain contract expires.